# check if row exists else create one

Tags: php, mysql

**Motive:**  I just want to crreate a row tih specified data if one with the same data does not exists.
Thing I have tried so far is -

**CODE:**

```
<?php
if(empty($_GET['a'])) {$xyz ="new";} else{$xyz=$_GET['a'];}
$servername = "mysql.soemwhere.com";
$username = "u130204422_acb";
$password = "YES-I-KNOW";
$dbname = "u130204422_acb";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$output ="SELECT * FROM trailers
WHERE url='$xyz' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$output);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 $pid=$row["title"];
echo $pid;}
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {echo 'yes';}
else{
$msql = "INSERT INTO `trailers`(`url`,`title`) VALUES ('$xyz','dekhlia')";
if ($conn->query($msql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully. Refrsh the page and it will echo dekhlia";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;}
echo "hehe";
$conn->close();} 
?>
```

I am unable to figure out why this code is'nt working.

Comment: What means "why this code is'nt working"? Any error message? Unexpected output?

Comment: Check if there are any query errors! If `mysqli_query()` returns `false`, print error: `printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: No it was just echoing out new record created succesfully, even if the record was there.

Comment: Thanks for your help now everything is working fine and I will accept the answer as soon as 8 minutes pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unnecessarily adding concatenation in the SQL string.

Its a part of the sting, so, remove it.

Change

```
$output ="SELECT * FROM trailers
WHERE url='.$xyz.' LIMIT 1";
```

To:

```
$output ="SELECT * FROM trailers
WHERE url='$xyz' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: guess what, i just edited that in the code but it it still giving empty response.

Comment: Thanks that was a small error now the code is perfectly working.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please mark it as solution.

Comment: sure let 8 minutes pass.